# Codeigniter: Is encrypting a password like this secure?

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

I was wondering if someone could me some advice please?  I was wondering how secure/insecure or otherwise rubbish the following code is for encrypting passwords using Codeigniter?

```
$safe_password = sha1($password, $config['encryption_key'])
```

If not secure can people give me some tips to make it more secure using Codeigniter please?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Because sha1 function returns longer, thus more secure hashes. As well, hash() has no encryption key, so there will be same hash keys on different domains.

Comment: If you're not particularly avoiding a module like Ion Auth, why not go with something like that?

Comment: More info from the PHP docs on hashing passwords: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Comment: possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords) - Since everyone else is posting generic (i.e. none-codeigniter) answers.

Answer (score 2):

sha1 has been know to be vulnerable to collision attacks, try using bcrypt as it's one of the best. If bcrypt doesn't work for you use sha512 and add a salt too.
bcrypt may seem daunting to use but here's an article on why you should use it: http://phpmaster.com/why-you-should-use-bcrypt-to-hash-stored-passwords/

The reason why sha1 is unsecure is because of collision attacks, here is one of the papers where it exposes sha1's security risks: http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/cryptanalysis_o.html

If you would like to use sha512 all you need to do is:

```
hash('sha512', $password.$salt);
```

And make sure you always use a salt or else some one can use a rainbow table (database) to see if your hash matches a common password inside the database.

Comment: SHA-1 is still resistant to [preimage attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is with bcrypt, have a look at this [tutorial](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Here is a small library that you can use with Codeigniter https://github.com/waldirbertazzijr/codeigniter-bcrypt

Another related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php/6337021#6337021).

Answer (score 0):

Hashing algorithms such as sha1 and md5 are not suitable for password storing. They are designed to be very efficient. This means that brute forcing is very fast. Even if a hacker obtains a copy of your hashed passwords, it is pretty fast to brute force it. If you use a salt, it makes rainbow tables less effective, but does nothing against brute force. Using a slower algorithm makes brute force ineffective. For instance, the bcrypt algorithm can be made as slow as you wish, and it uses salts internally to protect against rainbow tables. I would go with such an approach or similar if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP DOC

> string sha1 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
>   If the optional **raw_output is set to TRUE**, then the sha1 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 20, otherwise the returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number.

My Advice use `BCRYPT` its more secure for easy implementation you can try [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Example

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `sha1()` is not considered secure as can be read, for example, here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Currently, a good choice might be SHA512 using a salt: `hash('sha512', 'text+salt')`